# WSO2 Greg and ESB integration samples

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am attempting to use Greg to hold endpoint URL's for services deployed into non-WSO2 containers (Weblogic/JBoss). I would like to use WSO2 ESB to perform mediation and routing of data through these endpoints.

However, when I look at the WSO2 ESB samples, it is not clear how I instruct the ESB to use WSO2's Greg. Below is the xml used to have the ESB use a registry deployed to the filesystem.

```
<definitions xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">    
    <registry provider="org.wso2.carbon.mediation.registry.ESBRegistry">
        <parameter name="root">file:./repository/samples/resources/</parameter>        
        <parameter name="cachableDuration">15000</parameter>    
    </registry>
 </definitions>
```

My assumption is that the registry tag's provider element should probably be able to be overridden with a web-service address providing access to Greg.

When all is said and done, I would like to create simple BPMN configuration files that connect to Greg, obtain URI's and URL's for the services used by the file, and then to reference them as properties later in the BPMN route.

First question, is this a standard configuration, or is there a better way to integrate WSO ESB and Greg.

Second question, are there any examples I could refer to that will answer this question?

Answer (score 3):

Please refer following documentation.

[1] http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/2010/04/sharing-registry-space-across-multiple-product-instances

[2]http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Storing+Various+WSO2+Enterprise+Service+Bus+Configurations

Those include how you can store and using WSO2 governance registry in highlevel.

If you need to manage endpoints through API in governance registry following will help.

[3] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance453/Endpoints+with+Governance+API

[4] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance453/Endpoint+Look-up+Sample

Futher this thread include some of the hints how you can access custom stored properties in Registry

[5][How to access system property from WSO2 ESB and Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210972/how-to-access-system-property-from-wso2-esb-and-registry)

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Governance Registry is a meta data repository, therefore you can use it to store the SOA artifacts (WSDL,Schems,Policies, Mediation configurations , customs artifacts ..etc) of your deployment. After that you can govern  those artifacts through the Governance Registry. You can find more details in the ESB documentation[1].

[1]http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Config+and+Governance+Partitions+in+a+Remote+Registry

Thanks & Regards,

Ajith