# WSO2 Read JVM environment argument into property mediator or endpoint mediator

Tags: wso2, esb

I am storing the servername and port as a JVM argument (e.g. -Dservername=blah,-Dserverport=blah

Is there any way to set an endpoint address to read from these values?  Is there an easier way than creating a custom mediator to store the variables in the message context?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the system property from class mediator, set properties to synapsecontext, then use that within sequence..

Check this similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210972/how-to-access-system-property-from-wso2-esb-and-registry)

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I also found I could potentially use Pojo Command: http://wso2.com/project/esb/java/4.0.0/docs/mediators/pojo-command.html