# WSO2 ESB Pass Registry file into Custom Mediator

Tags: drools, kie, wso2-esb

In WSO2 ESB registry I have a DRL file

**/opt/config/rules.drl**

```
rule ""
when
    ...
then
    ...
end
```

I want to use this file to fire Drools rules using a custom mediator with Kie

**DroolsMediator.java**

```
class DroolsMediator extends AbstractMediator {
    public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) {
        KnowledgeBuilder builder...
        URL url = new URL("path/to/registry/rules.drl");
        builder.add(ResourceFactory.newUrlResource(url), ResourceType.DRL);
        ...
    }
}
```

I have tried to get as a property but with no success:

```
<property name="REGISTRY-VALUE"
          expression="get-property('registry', '/opt/config/rules.drl')"/>
```

What approach should I take to passing registry items into custom mediators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't so much with the code as it was with where I was placing resources within the WSO2 Registry.

Inside the WSO2, there are **three** kinds of registries:

**Local Registry**

Entries are stored on the local filesystem and accessed as follows:

```
<localEntry key="Drools" src="/path/to/rules.drl" />
```

These can only be accessed by the ESB on the same machine as the resource.

**Configuration Registry**

Entries are uploaded to the WSO2 ESB and actually stored in a database, not the filesystem. They can be accessed under the registry location `/_system/config/` as follows:

```
<property name="Drools" expression="get-property('conf:/path/to/rules.drl')" />
```

**Governance Registry**

Entries are uploaded and stored just like in the configuration registry. They can be accessed under the registry location `/_system/config/` as follows:

```
<property name="Drools" expression="get-property('gov:/path/to/rules.drl')" />
```

The primary difference between the configuration and governance registries seems to be that configuration entries should be "product-specific" whereas governance entries are "global". This isn't enforced.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below links

http://vvratha.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/accessing-registry-resources-from-class.html

[How to access system property from WSO2 ESB and Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210972/how-to-access-system-property-from-wso2-esb-and-registry)