# WSO2 ESB: Get URI in property from HTTP/Address Endpoint?

Tags: apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I have a centrally defined endpoint that points to a RESTful API. At the moment it's a HTTP endpoint, but I can also work with an address endpoint if required.

**My issue is that I can't seem to find a way to access the endpoint URI in a property mediator** (much like you would be able to with a LocalEntry). I need to embed the URI in a subsequent request, so I'd like to do something like:

```
<property name="api_endpoint" expression="get-property('ApiEndpoint')"/>
```

Where `ApiEndpoint` is the centrally defined endpoint in the ESB. I later can then use a PayloadFactory mediator to embed this in further requests.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Strainy

## Update 11/01

Something similar to the following answer would do nicely: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15265345/1784962

If I could access the configuration registry and get the endpoint XML configuration similar to the below property, that would be fantastic:

```
<property name="test" 
          expression="string(get-property('registry', 'conf:/endpoints/Drupal_Endpoint.xml')//@uri-template)"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @ajanthan-eliyatham for providing the hint around setting a dynamic endpoint! It turns out this was a simple fix, but I'd like to go into slightly more detail than what ajanthan has presented (though if anyone - including ajanthan - would like to expand on my answer, I'm happy to mark it as correct).

It's important that you select "**Save in Registry**" (as indicated in the image below) when saving an endpoint. This will prompt you to provide a key for storage in the configuration registry of the ESB.

[image]

A dynamic endpoint will be created:
[image]

You can reference the full XML configuration in your sequence like so:

```
<property name="drupal_ep"
                expression="get-property('registry','conf:/Drupal_Endpoint')"
                scope="default"
                type="OM"/>
```

But, like me, if you're only interested in the uri-template component of the configuration you can use the following XPATH Query to extract the relevant attribute:

```
<property name="drupal_ep"
                expression="get-property('registry','conf:/Drupal_Endpoint')"
                scope="default"
                type="OM"/>
<property name="drupal_uri" 
          expression="get-property('drupal_ep')//@uri-template"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on my understanding you are trying to set dynamic endpoint. You can achieve this using HTTP Endpoint Template [1]. Find the below sample proxy service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="DynamicEndPointProxyService"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="endpoint_1"
                   value="http://ajanthan-ThinkPad-T440p:8089/test/get"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="SET ENDPOINT: " expression="get-property('endpoint_1')"/>
         </log>
         <send>
            <endpoint name="endpointName"
                      template="HttpEndPointTemplate"
                      uri="${endpoint_1}"/>
         </send>
         <log level="full"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Working+with+Templates

Update if this is what you expected.

Thanks.
Ajanthan

Comment: Hi Ajanthan, where are you retrieving the "endpoint_1" property from? Is it associated with your centrally defined endpoints? For ease of configuration, my question refers to using the already defined endpoints (i.e. the ones you define under the **Endpoints** screen in the ESB admin console UI). Hopefully you can still help me out :)

Comment: Think i made a mistake when renaming the property. The property part should be like this. <property name="endpoint_1"                   value="http://ajanthan-ThinkPad-T440p:8089/test/get"                  type="STRING"/> and defining the endpoint url here.  Is your requirement is getting the uri from already defined endpoints. Please add a sample proxy you have. It will help to give a solution.

Comment: Hi Ajanthan, thanks for helping. But I'm looking for something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15265345/1784962 - I've tried accessing the endpoint config in a property with the following expression: string(get-property('registry','conf:/endpoints/My_Endpoint.xml')//@uri-template) - but I'm not getting anything.